# How to connect LDAP using SSL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP to authenticate the user. Here is my code, but i am cant able to set the SSL using my c# code.

```
using LdapConnection = Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection;
using LdapException = Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException;

 var ldapHost = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP_HOST"];
 var ldapPort = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP_PORT"];

 connection.Connect(ldapHost, Convert.ToInt32(ldapPort));
 sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append(ldapLocation).Append(userName).Append(",").Append(ldapLocationIndia);
 connection.Bind(LdapConnection.Ldap_V3, sb.ToString(), password);
```

I got a message from my application security team i am sending the plain password, So i try to secure that by setting the authentication type as secure by try setting the option by

```
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
```

but i didnt see any Sessionoption in my connection object, I am using novel.ldap dll for my LDAP operation.

Any body help me please? How to send the password in a secure way over network for ldap server for authentication.

I am using port 636.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you familiar with google..? 
[Connect to LDAP using SSL](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23%20connect%20to%20LDAP%20using%20SSL)

Comment: hellooo, i tried, my question is i am not getting sessionopions property in my connection object. That is my question ok.

Comment: here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850860/how-do-i-validate-active-directory-creds-over-ldap-ssl

Comment: @DJKRAZE That example is using `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection` not `Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skimming the API, I think it's just

```
connection.SecureSocketLayer = true;
```

without the `SessionOptions` before you call `Connect`.

If you just wanted to secure the `Bind` you could do that by calling `connection.startTLS()` beforehand and `stopTLS()` afterwards (see Samples\StartTLS.cs in the download), but it sounds like you want full ldaps if you're using port 636.

Comment: non of the above option is coming in connection object, am i missing any reference

Comment: And your connection object is an LdapConnection from the latest version of the Novell.Ldap SDK (2009-07-14 is the last entry in ChangeLog.txt)? If it's a plain Connection not an LdapConnection then I think you want `.Ssl` instead, but I think you need to work with LdapConnection really.

Comment: hi thanks, now its working fine, i have the old dll before, downloaded the recent version, working cool. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi i am getting object reference error during connect after setting   connection.SecureSocketLayer = true; but its working fine if comment the above code. any help please?