# LDAP over SSL returns 'unwilling to perform' error when setting fast concurrent bind (PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials)

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

Initially issue started with .NET\C# and [ValidateCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889(v=vs.110).aspx) method - without SSL it works, with SSL it returns 'The server cannot handle directory requests'. But I narrowed it down and simplified to C++ code posted below.

MSDN says that [LDAP_OPT_FAST_CONCURRENT_BIND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367019(v=vs.85).aspx#LDAP_OPT_FAST_CONCURRENT_BIND) supports multiple simple binds and does not work with next 2 options: [LDAP_OPT_SIGN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367019(v=vs.85).aspx#LDAP_OPT_SIGN), [LDAP_OPT_ENCRYPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367019(v=vs.85).aspx#LDAP_OPT_ENCRYPT). It also says that using simple binds without SSL is [not good](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366995(v=vs.85).aspx) as you will expose your credentials in clear text when sent over the network.

So, seems like when you are using LDAP over SSL without signing and encryption you are okay to enable FCB. But every time I do this I receive 0x35 (Unwilling to perform). [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367028(v=vs.85).aspx) about password authentication says nothing about SSL also. So, the question is - what am I doing wrong? Or, may be Microsoft should state in their documentation that SSL is not supported with LDAP_OPT_FAST_CONCURRENT_BIND?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winldap.h>

int main()
{
    PCHAR username = "bla-bla-bla";
    PCHAR password = "bla-bla-bla";
    PCHAR hostName = "bla-bla-bla";
    ULONG lRtn = 0;
    LDAP* pLdapConnection = NULL;

    pLdapConnection = ldap_init(hostName, LDAP_PORT);

    // NOTE: those 2 below - will return 0x35 (Unwilling to perform) during setting LDAP_OPT_FAST_CONCURRENT_BIND option
    //pLdapConnection = ldap_init(hostName, LDAP_SSL_PORT);
    //pLdapConnection = ldap_sslinit(hostName, LDAP_SSL_PORT, 1);

    if (pLdapConnection == NULL)
    {
        printf("ldap_init failed with 0x%x.\n", LdapGetLastError());
        ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("ldap_init succeeded \n");

    lRtn = ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL);
    if (lRtn == LDAP_SUCCESS)
        printf("ldap_connect succeeded \n");
    else
    {
        printf("ldap_connect failed with 0x%lx.\n", lRtn);
        ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
        return -1;
    }

    // Enable concurrent binding - returns 0x35 when used with SSL.
    lRtn = ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_FAST_CONCURRENT_BIND, LDAP_OPT_ON);
    if (lRtn == LDAP_SUCCESS)
        printf("Fast concurrent binding enabled\n");
    else
    {
        printf("SetOption Error:%0lX\n", lRtn);
        ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
        return -1;
    }

    lRtn = ldap_simple_bind_s(pLdapConnection, username, password);
    if (lRtn == LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("ldap_simple_bind_s succeeded \n");
        password = NULL;         // Remove password pointer
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ldap_bind_s failed with 0x%lx.\n", lRtn);
        ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
        return -1;
    }

    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Found that server support should be enabled to use FCBs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223355.aspx . And I could not see that OID in my server's RootDSE. Strange thing that it does work without SSL anyway.

Answer (score 1):

See my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49310208/1950304.

> Or, may be Microsoft should state in their documentation that SSL is not supported with LDAP_OPT_FAST_CONCURRENT_BIND?

It's not SSL in general, it's *mutual* SSL.